# request.body returning empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

My `request.body` is returning an empty object in express 4.17.1.
It works fine on postman, but when I try consuming it at the frontend using javascript I get an empty object, even when I `console.log` it

Below is my code:

```
/////Express backend

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

////React frontend
 const myData = {   
  _id: "616a4663c3086a539a8c3dcc",
  type: "describe_yourself",
  name: "white"
 }


React.useEffect( () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:9000/test', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
      body: JSON.stringify(myData)
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))

}, [])
```

I am not using `body-parser` because it is deprecated.
I will really appreciate anyone that can help me. thanks in advance

Comment: Are you calling fetchdata() anywhere? You've written this as a function which calls fetch.

Comment: i am calling it on load of the page..

Comment: You'll need to document this question a little more in depth (api, routes, postman, etc...) Because your code here seems good so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Although it could be as simple as capitalizing `Content-Type` but I don't think so...

Comment: add app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); - https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded

Comment: Can you please try if this is returning some data or not?

React.useEffect( () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:9000/test', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
      body: JSON.stringify(myData)
    }).then(response => console.log(response))

}, [])

Comment: Why are you using React inside of an express project? I thought useEffect was only available to React Components?

Comment: @DraganS adding app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));  solve it for me..thanks

Comment: @Ivan they are two difference project. react frontend and express backend

Comment: @DayanaScott I would suggest you edit the question then so the code is separated.